passing data from one page to another in nextjs
so I have been making a website and I am making a registration page for people to sign up but I need to check if the email is valid or not and because of that i can't use Link. cause I need to redirect it to a new page where i can show them the results if it was success or not and then show them some stats like how many registration do we have till now. I apologise for my mistakes and ignorance in advance
I don't wanna add the data in the url cause that wouldn't be clean. So if you can, can you please tell me a way to send the data between pages using Link but maybe I can do it a little more programmatically. Like after I have done all my operations and I have sent the data to my database and saved it, I can pass the email to the next page
Thank you for your help

When you redirect to a new page, you use Router in NextJS. That's the way to pass params.
Router.push({
  pathname: '/result',
  query: { email: 'a@email.com' }
})

Then in the result page
const router = useRouter();

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(router.query.email);
}, [router.query]);


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Yeah I actually figured it out. It is too complicated I just sent back an object with my id and then just pass to the next page and then show it out.
